# angular schema form: enum translation

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-translate, angular-schema-form

I have a select, its schema looks like this:

```
type: {
  type: 'string',
  enum: ['Event', 'BusinessEvent', 'ComedyEvent', ... ],
  default: 'Event'
}
```

and its form def like this:

```
{
  key: 'type',
  title: $translate.instant('templates.forms.event.type'),
  feedback: false
}
```

I'm using angular translate for the i18n. The select works flawlessly, however I haven't found a way to translate the actual items in the enum. Is there a way to do this?

I was thinking of something in the form def like this:

```
{
  key: 'type',
  title: $translate.instant('templates.forms.event.type'),
  feedback: false,
  showAs: function(value) {
    return $translate.instant('templates.forms.event.' + value);
  }
}
```